# Data from Sql Database to an Array

Tags: java, android, sql, arrays, eclipse

I would like to put some data from a Sql database in an Array

Here is my code for the array:

```
openDB();
Cursor c = myDb.getSpalte();
while (!c.isAfterLast()) 
     {
         s1nInt[i]  = c.getInt(1);
         i++;
         c.moveToNext();
     }
c.close();
closeDB();
```

And here is my code for the `getSpalte();` Method:

```
public Cursor getSpalte()
{
    String where= null;
    Cursor c =  db.query(true, DATABASE_TABLE, KEY_KALOA, 
            where, null, null, null, null, null);
    if (c != null) 
    {
      c.moveToFirst();
    }
  return c;
}
```

And if I run this I get these Exception:

```
06-27 13:34:01.021: E/CursorWindow(24334): Failed to read row 0, column 1 from a CursorWindow which has 1 rows, 1 columns.
```

now I got for these command an exception:

```
  Number[] series2Numbers = {/*s1nInt[i-6],s1nInt[i-5],s1nInt[i-4],s1nInt[i-3],s1nInt[i-   2],s1nInt[i-1],*/s1nInt[i]};
```

This is my Exception for this:

```
Graph.onStart() line: 75    
Graph(Fragment).performStart() line: 1801   
FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(Fragment, int, int, int, boolean) line: 937 
FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(int, int, int, boolean) line: 1106  
BackStackRecord.run() line: 690 
FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions() line: 1571 
FragmentManagerImpl$1.run() line: 447   
Handler.handleCallback(Message) line: 733
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cursor starts at 0 and must be moved to the first row before accessing data:

```
     while(c.moveToNext())
     {
         s1nInt[i]  = c.getInt(1);
         i++;
     }
```

Comment: Thanks it works:) but could you help me on my next problem?:)